# Manage Undo stack of Ms word document

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, office-interop, word-addins

I am developing Ms word add ins and facing problem for managing Undo stack.

What actually i want is when i under line some word in document it record that action in undo stack.
i want to stop adding this item(Word Underline) in undo stack or remove that item(Word Underline) from undo stack.

so when user press undo button or press Ctrl + Z then it bypass last action(Word underline) and perform it's previous action.

I have try following code but that clear whole undo stack.

```
this.Application.ActiveDocument.UndoClear();
```

Here i want to remove only Underline effect from undo stack.

Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: This sound like a very bad idea... Even most basic case when "underline" stays when word is gone due to undo is hard to reasonable handle...

Answer (score 1):

The Word object model and application design does not support this. Undo must always go backwards from the last item. It can't "pick-and-peck".

It's no possible to tell whether what's described in the question is the actual problem, or only a simple example to illustrate. That makes suggesting alternatives difficult. But in general terms, it would be necessary to somehow "mark" such sections of text, perhaps with invisible content controls or bookmarks or a specific character style so that code can re-find them, later.